# comma operator safely used to return pointer in C

Tags: c, pointers, memory-management

Is the following code safe? Is it possible that the `ptr` returned by the macro `gen_call()`
may contain garbage value since it is not initialized to NULL. I was of the assumption that the comma operator is always evaluated left to right and should return NULL in case of error. I'm using gcc 3.4 on a Linux system.

```
#define gen_call() (ptr = get_pointer(), ptr)

void*
get_pointer()
{
  if (random()%2 == 0) {
      void *ptr = calloc(sizeof(int));
      return ptr;
  }
  return NULL;
}

int main()
{
  void *ptr;

  ptr = gen_call();
  if (!ptr) {
     return -1;
  }
  *ptr = 1;
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Is `#include <stdlib.h>` present or not in the code? It affects safeness of the code. `gcc 3.4` is 18 years old

Comment: @sinbad The function get_pointer returns eirther a valid pointer or NULL. So neither garbage will be returned But in any case it is better to write just ptr = get_pointer(); instead of ptr = gen_call();

Comment: "I'm using gcc 3.4" Are you stuck in 2004? Need help getting out, or... you know what, scratch that. How do I get back to 2004?

Comment: You don't need the comma and second "do-nothing" expression. That macro, without the extraneous bit, will become what is called "chaining", effectively assigning the returned value to `ptr` and then to `ptr` again... `ptr = ptr = get_pointer();`

Comment: `ptr = gen_call();` will be replaced by the preprocessor with `ptr = (ptr = get_pointer(), ptr);`. What are you trying to achieve with it ?

Comment: @n.m.couldbeanAI It could possibly be last stable version of gcc. I'm not joking. Back in the days they had stable versions. Nowadays you probably need a server hall to host the Bugzilla db alone...

Comment: Sidenote: `calloc(sizeof(int));` Your compiler might raise some concerns.... Where is second parameter?

Comment: Re “I was of the assumption that the comma operator is always evaluated left to right and should return NULL in case of error”: The comma operator does not detect errors or create a null pointer. It evaluates the left operand, there is a sequence point, it evaluates the right operand, and its result is the value of the right operand. That is all.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the code is safe (but needlessly complicated). The comma operator guarantees left-to-right evaluation and there is a sequence point between the evaluation of the left and right operands. `ptr` will first get assigned the value from the function call and then it will get assigned to itself, which is safe but senseless.

You need to `#include <stdlib.h>`. If you have a very old gcc < version 5, then it defaults to GNU89 based on C89, where forgetting the include would break code using malloc.

Answer (score 0):

This is safe. `ptr_main = gen_call();` is equivalent to `ptr_main = (ptr_macro = get_pointer(), ptr_macro);`, which is equivalent to

```
ptr_macro = get_pointer();
ptr_main = ptr_macro;
```

Which doesn't make too much sense, but it's safe, because comma-separated expressions are evaluated from left to right and all assingments from one expression are fully processed before the next expression is evaluated.

(note: I renamed the variables for my answer; the compiler does not do that)

However... two remarks. First, as a general rule, you shouldn't have macros that reference variables, only the macro parameters. There are a few exceptions, but very few.

Second,  this does not work:

```
void *ptr;
*ptr = 1;
```

The dereference operator (`*pointer`) requires the pointer to contain the address of a data type of known size. Otherwise, how is the compiler supposed to know how many bytes it has to write? `(void*)` pointers are generic pointers which you can only use to pass around memory addresses. If you want to manipulate the memory that it is pointing, you need to cast the pointer to a type whose size is known. For example:

```
void *ptr:
*(int*)ptr = 1;
```

Although, of course, you don't need that. Just declare `int *ptr` in the first place.

Comment: there is no `ptr_main` and `ptr_macro`, there is only `ptr` . Macros are a text replacement, there's only one `ptr` in total

Comment: I know that and I did address it in my answer.

Comment: Your answer suggests there are two variables called `ptr` (e.g. you say "I renamed the variables") , however there is only one variable. The macro expands to `ptr = (ptr = get_pointer(), ptr)` and all `ptr` refer to the same one variable.